# locking global variable in 2 different function called by 2 different thread

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex

In below code I am incrementing global variable in 2 independent functions using 2 threads. I used lock guard. I got output like func1 completed first. After only func2 started. It like single thread code. So what should I do to lock only global variable instead of function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

// a global variable
int number;

std::mutex myMutex;

void func1(int interval)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (myMutex);
    for(int i = 0; i< interval; i++)
    {
        cout<<"thread one " << ++number<<std::endl;
    }
}

void func2(int interval)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (myMutex);
    for(int i = 0; i< interval; i++)
    {
        cout<<"thread two " << ++number<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(func1, 1000);
    std::thread t2(func2, 1000);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You hold the lock for the entirety of the function(s). Try taking/releasing the lock in a narrower scope where it is actually needed (like inside your loops.

Comment: note that if `number` was `std::atomic<int>` you wouldn't need a mutex at all

Comment: Be careful here: you are **not** locking a global variable; you are locking a mutex that protects **code** that **accesses** the global variable. If you add more code that accesses the variable the new code has to lock the mutex, too. The mutex manages **code**, not **data**. The way to actually lock a global variable is to make it `std::atomic<int>`. With that, every access is protected (that's a bit oversimplified), and it's reasonable to say that the global variable gets locked whenever it's used.

Comment: (1) remove the `std::mutex` as it's not needed, (2) change `int number;` to `std::atomic< int > number { 0 };`, (3) use a local to count the number of loop iterations and add to `number` after the loop has finished (Google "thread false sharing").

Answer (score 1):

Move the lock ***inside*** the `for` loop:

```
    for(int i = 0; i< interval; i++)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock (myMutex);
```

This will keep the lock only long enough to increment the shared object. The lock gets realized at the end of every iteration, and re-locked at the beginning. This gives the other execution thread an opportunity to grab it.

Note that this still does not guarantee any kind of a change in the observed results (but the change in the observed results will be more likely the larger the `interval` is). It is still theoretically possible for the resulting output to be completely unchanged. You have absolutely no guarantees, whatsoever, when it comes to locking order in absence of any other synchronization logic.